# What is this crustacean on my plate?

Tags: food-identification, spanish-cuisine

In Spain, I had this crustacean on my plate in a fidea dish. It was about 1.5 cm wide, around 10 cm long and did not really contain any meat worth eating. I’m wondering what this crustacean is called.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's called a [mantis shrimp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantis_shrimp) ("galeras" in Spain). They are edible and popular in Spain and Southern China.
However, as you observed, they are somewhat difficult and unrewarding to eat.

Comment: *galeras* are mostly used for broth, and usually crushed and strained away, they are very rarely served in the dish as in the picture.

Comment: I've had them served to me a couple times (I know not to order them now).  Using them for broth seems like a much better idea.